# jquery "Minified" "Uncompressed" files

Tags: jquery

I new with jquery and I can do simple coding with it.
and I want to know about these files more "Minified" "Uncompressed" and when I should use each one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The minified and compressed versions of each file are simply versions that have been reduced in size with the same functionality.  Use them when you put your code into production.  Use the "developer" versions while still making your web site and debugging your scripts.

Answer (score 9):

Uncompressed you use to **develop**, it's full of comments and useful variable names.  Minified you use to **actually send to clients** to save you some bandwidth and them some loading time.

Minified is effectively the same code, but no comments and a variable like `elementTagName` may simple be `t`...not very useful for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The minified version is for deployment, to minimise the size of downloads a user's browser has to make.

The uncompressed version is for development, since the minified version is very hard to debug with.